# Sync issue using Teams on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, microsoft-teams

We are using teams on my Ubuntu laptop but it is not syncing property so I see less files for example compared to accessing on a tablet.

Any suggestions to force a sync, clicking the icon doesn't do it.

Comment: This would be best asked over at https://superuser.com/ since it's not programming related. As new as this product is it might be a good idea to hit up microsoft forums directly as well (although they are rarely helpful).

Comment: This could be an issue with files. Are you facing this issue with any particular file type? 
 We are looking into this.

Comment: We are using it for home schooling, it's the class notebook that doesn't sync. We can see more files on other devices. I don't think it's caused by a particular file type, mostly PDF, PPT files.

Comment: @Andrew, I missed to post you. 
It is very difficult to check this without logs. I have filed a bug to test it further.